# Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL error - My link has the download attribute - in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a link which I am trying to use for downloading a pdf. I don't want the pdf to open in the browser, I just want it to download.

My link has the download attribute, and I set the href attribute to a data url using javascript. It starts "data:application/pdf;base64,"
When I click the link, nothing happens and I see an error in the console. "Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL: ..."

My link has the download attribute, so it shouldn't be trying to navigate the top-frame, but rather to download, which I thought should be allowed.

Here is what the link looks like, roughly:
 Download Pdf

This link is in an ASP.NET MVC .cshtml page. I am using localhost.
When I tried copying the exact link into a regular html page and launching it using Live Server, the download worked fine.

If anyone has any insight into why this is happening or what I could do to work around it, that would be much appreciated.

Thank you!